# How to find current_streaks in BQ SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Looking for the best way to find all current streaks of **today** in BigQuery ( so essentially the answer must be `row_number()` based but otherwise any flavor SQL *should* do..).

```
 created_at  | user_id    
-------------+---------
  2022-02-10 | 1
  2022-02-09 | 1
  2022-02-08 | 1
  2022-02-10 | 2
  2022-01-20 | 3
```

Desired result only showing User_ID of the Streaker and their # of days Streaked

```
 user_id  | streak    
----------+---------
     1    |    3
     2    |    1
```

*`UserID: 2` is ignored because it's streak did not make it to today*

Answer (score 2):

You can add a condition outside the streak-identification code, which validates the existence of `current_date()` in the streak set and only display the valid streaks (i.e. ones which connect to today's date):

```
select user_id, array_length(array_agg(distinct created_at)) as streak from (
   select 
      user_id, 
      created_at, 
      date_sub(created_at, interval rnk day) as grp from (
         select 
            user_id, 
            date(created_at) as created_at, 
            dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as rnk
         from table
      )
   )
group by user_id, grp
having current_date() in unnest( array_agg(distinct created_at))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to pull only objects created on `current_date()` and then iterate backwards on them? I notice people say streaks are a gaps-and-islands problem, but the first gap would technically be the solution. Anyways, thanks so much. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think that is possible too, but it will surely take another iteration over the dataset to figure out all the streak elements (or islands) which connect all the way to `current_date()` and then join those with dates in this query.